# Python 3 Inheritance

Tags: class, oop, inheritance, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

I'm a bit of a beginner with OOP and have been trying to teach myself some of its concepts using Python3. However, I have gotten stuck with inheritance. This is my source code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

class TwoD:
    def __init__(self, height, width):
    self.h = height
    self.w = width
def perimeter(self, height, width):
    return 2 * (height + width)
def area(self, height, width):
    return height * width

class Cuboid(TwoD):
def __init__(self, height, width, depth):
    self.d = depth
def volume(self, height, width, depth):
    return height * width * depth

x = Cuboid(3, 4, 5)
print(x.volume())
print(x.perimeter())
print(x.area())
```

The error I get when I run it is below. It reads as though I need to add arguments to volume, but doesn't x provide it with the required variables?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./Class.py", line 19, in <module>
print(x.volume())
TypeError: volume() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'height', 'width', and 'depth'
```

So could someone please let me know what I am doing wrong. I'm sure it is something silly. Also, could someone please explain how I would go about using multiple inheritance in Python3?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Replace all your tabs with 4 spaces, please.

Answer (score 2):

Since in the `__init__()` method you are creating two *data attributes* `self.h` and `self.w`, you can use them in your other methods, so it's not necessary to pass any arguments:

```
def perimeter(self):
    return 2 * (self.h + self.w)

def area(self):
    return self.h * self.w
```

Also, in the `__init__()` method of the `Cuboid` class don't forget to call `super`, so `self.h` and `self.w` become *data attributes*.

Answer (score 1):

> It reads as though I need to add arguments to volume, but doesn't x
>   provide it with the required variables?

Yes, it does, which means you should not have them in the method definition at all:

```
class TwoD:
    def __init__(self, height, width):
        self.h = height
        self.w = width
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * (self.h + self.w)
    def area(self):
        return self.h * self.w
```

Etcetera. So in fact it's not inheritance which is the problem, but that your code was not object oriented at all.